# Does this pattern have a name?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented

I have a large XML file that I extract information from.

I am extracting the information using a list of classes with a main method of the type `ParsedValue[] GetValue(BigXmlFile)`.

This is a bit like a list of commands or strategies. Does this have a name?

Comment: XML deserialization?

Comment: *"This is a bit like a list of commands or strategies. Does this have a name?"*  - Maybe the command pattern or strategy pattern?

Comment: It's a list of data extractors, a command does not have a return value, and a strategy is supposed to replace another strategy as a singular thing. This is why it is not a command or a strategy.

Comment: [Recommended reading](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology)

Comment: @RobbieDee, that was an interesting read. I think this question falls under the "what is this thing" and not "how to name this thing". The question here being expanded to "is this a thing? and if so what is this thing's name?".

Comment: Since you're asking specifically about the GetValue() call itself, "deserialization" seems like the only sensible answer. The deserialized objects may be used as part of a command pattern or a strategy pattern later on, and the ability to serialize/deserialize these objects may be one of the benefits of those patterns, but the act of deserialization is almost certainly not a "design pattern" by itself.

Comment: Remember that the GoF patterns are about recurring structures and themes in software, they are not hard-and-fast recipes to be followed to the letter.    A command pattern which includes return values is still very much a command pattern.      Remember that the only reason for even assigning memorable names to patterns is to aid communication between developers.     If you said *"This deserialiser is implemented using a command pattern"* to another developer, they would immediately understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As some others have pointed out, the *main method* `GetValue(BigXmlFile)` is the only thing being asked about here. XML de-serialization is what is being done here in order to obtain the data from an external configuration file.

Therefore, I would say that this is not a pattern but a process. The process being used here is called de-serialization.